# Sub folders in document library not showing up on page

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I've a document library in which there are 7 items and two sub folders(these have 4 items each), but only the items are displayed on the page and sub folders are hidden for some reason.
The view of document library is not changed and the page has content editor web part which is linked to a html file(this has js file which has all the code to display a document library on a page).
Used this REST call to get all the items from the document library:
/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('GeneralDocuments')/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields,Folders,Files,Files/ListItemAllFields

Am using SharePoint 2013.

Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the endpoint using jquery ajax below, it's working to output the sub folder name in the page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('GeneralDocuments')/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields,Folders,Files,Files/ListItemAllFields",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.d.results);
            for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
            {
              $("#subfolderdiv").append(data.d.results[i].Name+"<br/>");

            }

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error");

        }
    });

});

</script>
<div id="subfolderdiv"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can check the Rest Endpoint in Browser directly to see if all the sub folders listed, in my side, no such issue, I can get all sub folders.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but currently am not looking for this. My requirement is to display all the folders within 'General Documents' document library. Only few folders are not displaying on a page(trying to find the reason)..these folders are showing up in REST call but not on page.
Am uploading a folder in 'explorer view', but it is not showing up on a page where 'General Documents' web part is present